# website performance issues when using ffmpeg on separate server

Tags: performance, ffmpeg, server, network-programming, remote-server

I am currently working on a site that uses wordpress and ffmpeg. I have it setup so that I have 3 servers - main, database, ffmpeg. So far I have it all working, however I am still running into issues when I am trying to encode a video.

Whenever I start encoding a video, if I try opening any other links in a new tab, it gets stuck on loading until ffmpeg is done. I dont understand why, since im using multiple servers.

My specs for my servers --

Main (web server) - 4 vCPUs / 8GB RAM / 160GB Disk

Database server - 2 vCPUs / 4GB RAM / 80GB Disk

Ffmpeg server - 8 vCPUs / 32GB / 640GB Disk

They are all in the same region as well, and I have private IPs as public for them. Public IPs uses IPv4.

On my template page I have a form that the users fills out and uploads images, then using ajax it sends the info to my ffmpeg functions in my functions.php file.

Images are uploaded to the main server and then on that server in my functions.php file I use ssh2 to login to the ffmpeg server and run different commands, for example --

```
$server   = "FFMPEG SERVER IP"; // server IP/hostname of the SSH server
$username = "user"; // username for the user you are connecting as on the SSH server
$password = "pass"; // password for the user you are connecting as on the SSH server
// Establish a connection to the SSH Server. Port is the second param.
$connection = ssh2_connect($server, 22);
// Authenticate with the SSH server
ssh2_auth_password($connection, $username, $password);
$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);
ssh2_sftp_mkdir($sftp, $thepathw);

$command = '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -threads 1 -i '.$thepath .'/audio.mp3 -safe 0 -f concat -i '.$thepath.'/paths.txt -vf "scale=1280:720,setsar=1" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -af "volume=-5dB" -c:v libx264 -movflags +faststart '.$fixedtime.' -y '.$output.' 2>&1';

// Execute a command on the connected server and capture the response
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $command);
// Sets blocking mode on the stream
stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
// Get the response of the executed command in a human readable form
$output1 = stream_get_contents($stream);
// echo output
echo $output1;
```

The video file that is created is then saved to the ffmpeg server.

This all works as should and Im able to create videos, but the rest of the site doesnt seem to respond/load until ffmpeg is done. This is a big problem since I plan on having multiple users at once on the site.

So how can I improve this setup so that the ffmpeg server doesnt slow down the main server, and multiple users can safely use the site?

Im also open to the idea of getting another server to upload my images to, instead of on the main. Im not sure if that would help though cause it seems like a lot of pulling/sending data between multiple sources/IPs may slow down the response time.

Any suggestions is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It could be due to file system IO locking issues.. Try to serve cached data while your files being modified..